# ¿Es posible incluir una lista dentro de otra lista en fish?

Tags: fish

Tengo determinada variable que es una lista y quiero saber si es posible en **fish** incluir otra lista como uno de los elementos de esta variable, y si es posible, cómo referenciar sus elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar un poco y escudriñar la no muy extensa bibliografía que hay sobre **fish** di con la solución.

Definitivamente en **fish** NO se pueden crear listas dentro de otras listas, pero SI hay una forma de simular la anidación.

Lo primero es declarar la variable que contendrá dentro de sus elementos una o más listas. Ej.:

Una variable llamada **lista_de_compras** que contendrá los elementos **pan**, **galletas**, **mantequilla** y **agua natural**

`set lista_de_compras pan galletas mantequilla "agua natural"`

Ahora, los elementos **pan** y **galletas** son listas. Para simular que son listas anidadas se deben declarar como variables independientes (OJO! Deben coincidir mayúsculas y minúsculas, de lo contrario no dará error, pero al referirse a ellas desde la lista principal las reconocerá como elementos vacíos)

`set pan "corteza dura" "corteza blanda"; set galletas 'dulces' 'saladas'`

Nótese que no es imprescindible emplear comillas simples (') o dobles (") para definir los elementos de la lista, a no ser que sea una cadena de dos o más elementos.

Ahora, para referirse a algún elemento dentro del elemento de la sub-lista, se debe referenciar la variable principal con un doble signo de dollar ($$) seguido del número que lo identifica encerrado entre corchetes ([ ]) y luego el número de la sub-lista también encerrado entre corchetes. Ej. :

El **pan de corteza dura** sería `$$lista_de_compras[1][1]`. Si no se especifica el elemento de la sub-lista, o sea, el segundo número entre corchetes, se estaría haciendo referencia a todos los elementos de de esa sub-lista. Ej:

`echo $$lista_de_compras[1]`

Daria cómo salida:

`corteza dura corteza blanda`

Por otra parte, si se hace referencia a la lista principal con $$ y no se especifica un elemento, se obtendrían como salida todos los elementos de todas las sub-lista.

He aquí un pequeño ejemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

# Lista de compras
set lista_de_compras Pan Galletas Mantequilla "Agua natural" 
set Pan "Corteza dura" "Corteza blanda" 
set Galletas Dulces Saladas

echo "LISTA DE COMPRAS:" $lista_de_compras\n

for a in (seq (count $lista_de_compras))
  echo $a-$lista_de_compras[$a]
  for b in (seq (count $$lista_de_compras[$a]))
    echo '    '- $$lista_de_compras[$a][$b]
  end
  echo
end
```